# Flatten layer output does not match input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, flatten

I am testing different network architectures for image classification. I have a dataset composed of many 270x270 frames and they should be classified among 3 different classes. The images are all in grayscale, so just one channel.

I am trying to use this simple architecture:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(128,7,activation = 'relu',padding = 'same',
                     input_shape = (270,270,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(256,3,activation = 'relu',padding = 'same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2))
model.add(Conv2D(384,3,activation = 'relu',padding = 'same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(64)) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.summary()
```

I am using ‍Adam‍ with `SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy` as the loss function.

This is the summary of the network:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 270, 270, 128)     6400      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 270, 270, 256)     295168    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 135, 135, 256)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 135, 135, 384)     885120    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 67, 67, 384)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1723776)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               220643456 
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 195       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 3)                 0         
=================================================================
```

Unfortunately, I receive this error once I try to do fit:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  
Input to reshape is a tensor with 24385536 values, but the requested
 shape requires a multiple of 1723776

[[node sequential/flatten/Reshape (defined at 
/home/deeplearner/workspace/deeplearning-pipeline-multisensor-
develop/src/bystronic_lib/deeplearning_tools.py:78) ]] 
[Op:__inference_train_function_983]
```

The error is related to the Flatten layer: `(None, 1723776)` is the output shape of the Flatten layer as it is written in the network summary too. I do not understand why the input is wrong. My network is very simple.

What I noticed is that if I remove all the dense part of the network after the Flatten layer (that is to say: if I build a network that it is only Convolutional) everything works.

For example this network works without any issue:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 270, 270, 1) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, 270, 270, 16) 160         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNorma (None, 270, 270, 16) 64          conv2d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)         (None, 270, 270, 16) 0           batch_normalization[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 270, 270, 64) 9280        activation[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 270, 270, 64) 256         conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 270, 270, 64) 0           batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 270, 270, 64) 36928       activation_1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 270, 270, 64) 1088        activation[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add (Add)                       (None, 270, 270, 64) 0           conv2d_2[0][0]                   
                                                                 conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, 270, 270, 64) 256         add[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)       (None, 270, 270, 64) 0           batch_normalization_2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 270, 270, 64) 36928       activation_2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (BatchNor (None, 270, 270, 64) 256         conv2d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)       (None, 270, 270, 64) 0           batch_normalization_3[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)               (None, 270, 270, 64) 36928       activation_3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_1 (Add)                     (None, 270, 270, 64) 0           add[0][0]                        
                                                                 conv2d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (BatchNor (None, 270, 270, 64) 256         add_1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)       (None, 270, 270, 64) 0           batch_normalization_4[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 135, 135, 128 73856       activation_4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (BatchNor (None, 135, 135, 128 512         conv2d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)       (None, 135, 135, 128 0           batch_normalization_5[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, 135, 135, 128 147584      activation_5[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               (None, 135, 135, 128 8320        activation_4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_2 (Add)                     (None, 135, 135, 128 0           conv2d_7[0][0]                   
                                                                 conv2d_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (BatchNor (None, 135, 135, 128 512         add_2[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)       (None, 135, 135, 128 0           batch_normalization_6[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 135, 135, 128 147584      activation_6[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (BatchNor (None, 135, 135, 128 512         conv2d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_7 (Activation)       (None, 135, 135, 128 0           batch_normalization_7[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)              (None, 135, 135, 128 147584      activation_7[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_3 (Add)                     (None, 135, 135, 128 0           add_2[0][0]                      
                                                                 conv2d_10[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_8 (BatchNor (None, 135, 135, 128 512         add_3[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_8 (Activation)       (None, 135, 135, 128 0           batch_normalization_8[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)              (None, 68, 68, 256)  295168      activation_8[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_9 (BatchNor (None, 68, 68, 256)  1024        conv2d_11[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_9 (Activation)       (None, 68, 68, 256)  0           batch_normalization_9[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)              (None, 68, 68, 256)  590080      activation_9[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)              (None, 68, 68, 256)  33024       activation_8[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_4 (Add)                     (None, 68, 68, 256)  0           conv2d_12[0][0]                  
                                                                 conv2d_13[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_10 (BatchNo (None, 68, 68, 256)  1024        add_4[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_10 (Activation)      (None, 68, 68, 256)  0           batch_normalization_10[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)              (None, 68, 68, 256)  590080      activation_10[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_11 (BatchNo (None, 68, 68, 256)  1024        conv2d_14[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_11 (Activation)      (None, 68, 68, 256)  0           batch_normalization_11[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_15 (Conv2D)              (None, 68, 68, 256)  590080      activation_11[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_5 (Add)                     (None, 68, 68, 256)  0           add_4[0][0]                      
                                                                 conv2d_15[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_12 (BatchNo (None, 68, 68, 256)  1024        add_5[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_12 (Activation)      (None, 68, 68, 256)  0           batch_normalization_12[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d (AveragePooli (None, 8, 8, 256)    0           activation_12[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 16384)        0           average_pooling2d[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 3)            49155       flatten[0][0]
```

About the above network, it is important to look at the last layers only: after the Flatten, there is immediately the last layer.
I tested other architectures and each time I put the last layer immediately after the Flatten everything works.
If I try to put multiple Dense layers after the Flatten, I always get the same error message.

Comment: I think it is because of wrong input data shape. After flatten layer it expects, for 1 sample to get 1723776 vector size, for 2 samples 2*1723776 and therefore a multiple of 1723776 after flatten layer. But your input data seems not to be 270*270 or not with 1 channel, and the output of flatten layers gets something else. Please add your model.fit and codes where you prepare your input. Check all of your images are in grayscale. and 270x270

Comment: Looks like issue with your input image shape. Flatten layer output `(None, 1723776)`, and which expects input `(67, 67, 384)`.You are getting different value at `max_pooling2d_1` which is something like `(252, 252, 384)`. Check your input image, make all the images of same shape and grayscale. Thanks!